# jQuery custom menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

every jQuery plugin I've found is based on `<li>` elements to generate the menu items.

I have `<div id = "menubutton">` element that represents the menu *button* and another, not-related (maning it is not a child) `<div id = "menucontent">` that contains the menu items (mixed stuff, images etc). I want this second, hidden div to appear when I click on the button. it should hide back when i leave the button OR when i leave the content div, in case i'm selecting items or doing stuff there.

Now, this is the code I have so far, but the clearTimeout thing doesn't seem to work. Any help? Pointing out a plugin to help my work would work as well.

Thanks!

```
        var timer;

        $('#menubutton').click(function() {
            $('#menucontent').show();
        });

        $('#menubutton').mouseout(function() {
            timer = setTimeout('$("#menucontent").hide()', 500);
        });


        $('#menucontent').mouseover(function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }).mouseout(function() {
            setTimeout('$("#menucontent").hide()', 300);
        });
```

**EDIT SOLUTION**

I solved the problem using `hover` insted of mouseover / mouseout

Comment: why would you make it work to leave the button or the content div? That would be annoying if you got stuck between the two borders and shit just starts disappearing for no reason. One or the other, not both. Is this script throwing up any errors in the error console?

Comment: no errors on the console. btw, if i one the menu, do not cross it and just go on another button, it would remain opened. it is just the way standard menues work, i think

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $('#menubutton').click(function() {
        $('#menucontent').show();
    });

    $('#menubutton').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).data('myTimer', setTimeout('$("#menucontent").hide()', 500));
    });

    $('#menucontent').mouseover(function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('myTimer'));
    }).mouseout(function() {
        setTimeout('$("#menucontent").hide()', 300);
    });
```

Comment: Interesting.  In that case, I'd recommend adding some debugging visuals so you can see exactly what's being called when, like a green box that shows when the menubutton mouseout happens, a red one for the menucontent mouseover, a blue one for the menucontent mouseout, etc.  Something isn't happening in the way you're expecting...